# ace editor - move to the end of the line

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm using [ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about). Sometimes, and I can not say exactly when (I put the text editor in ajax), Of the text cursor moves to the end of the line only there to write. Only if I refresh the page again, it works out.

Here is the code:

```
var ace_editor = null;
// Than I call to ajax to get the content of the ace editor
ace_editor = ace.edit("editbox");
ace_editor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
ace_editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
ace_editor.getSession().setValue(ParseResponseRules(xmlhttp.responseText));
```

Comment: show us your codes please.

Comment: Could you clarify the description of your question it's not very understandable.
Are cursor and text misaligned, or it's readonly depending on cursor position?

Comment: The cursor "going" to the and of the row. It's like I pressed the "end" key in the keyboard. Even I click on the start of the line, the cursor move to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ace_editor.setValue(ParseResponseRules(xmlhttp.responseText), -1);
```

instead of:

```
ace_editor.getSession().setValue(ParseResponseRules(xmlhttp.responseText));
```

The second parameter explained: undefined or 0 is selectAll, -1 is at the document start, and 1 is at the end

Ref: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor